# Django Update Table Immediately After Save()

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to insert an order info into two tables `Order` and `User`

I can save the values for both tables but getting an error when trying to update the `Order` table with the `User ID` from the record that was just created in the `User` table.

**Error:**

`Cannot assign "54L":"Order.user" must be a "User" instance.`

**view.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    userform = UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            #save both tables
            userform.save()
            form.save()

            #get user ID 
            user_info = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).order_by('-id')[0]

            #update order with user ID
            u = Order.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[0]
            u.user = user_info.id
            u.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
else:
    form = OrderForm()
    ...
```

Comment: Did you just try: `u.user=user_info` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change u.user = user_info.id to u.user = user_info